# Newly deployed website (in new environment) renders slowly in IE only

Tags: asp.net, firefox, iis-7, internet-explorer-8, windows-server-2008-r2

We have a brand new deployment environment for testing asp.net website builds. I’ve deployed the latest version of the website to this new server (decent specification, by no means a slouch) but when I hit the new pages in IE they render horrendously slow, taking about a minute to render the page. However, in Firefox and other browsers it renders correctly at normal speed (sub 1-second).
Given it renders fine in all other browsers, and works correctly when running the code locally in IE 7 & 8, I’m assuming its an environment/setup issue but do not know what to check as to why it is rendering so poorly in IE. The server is 2008r2 running IIS7.

If anyone has any ideas what is causing this, it would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Can you check the server logs, and see if it is requesting files the entire time it is rendering? Or can it get all the files quickly, and is just super slow to actually render content?

Answer (score 0):

You may have already checked this but if you are using the web site project model then the application is not precompiled before deployment.  "Because the pages must be automatically compiled when they are first visited, there can be a short but noticeable delay when an ASP.NET page is requested for the first time after being deployed."   *[ASP.NET reference](http://www.asp.net/hosting/tutorials/precompiling-your-website-vb)  If you are always hitting your site with IE first after deployment; that may explain why the delay appears to be only occuring in IE.

Comment: no, unfortunately, this happens every time a page is hit. I.e deploy, hit the page 10 times in each browser, renders fast in Firefox and terrible in IE for every impression, not just the first compilation run. In fact, its significantly slower than the standard compilation run! :(